# HyperLink on the mail send from Unix

Tags: unix, email, hyperlink

I am sending some text messages from the unix box to the normal internet mail id.

I Wanted to add a hyper link in those mails, but link to a file on the system not to a URL.

I'm doing it on local machine and i'm sending mail to my email-id.
In that mail, I need a link to file which resides on my system itself.

How I can do this?

Comment: How does the recipient see your machine - is it a local network? or ftp?

Comment: I'm testing it on my system for now.

Comment: Then there are several ways locally but they will not all work on a network so we do need to know. Otherwise you get the local solution that you have accepted which will not work on the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your URL like this:

```
file:///full/path/to/file
```

Of course, that will only work locally. If clicked on another system, it'll refer to their local filesystem.

Comment: Explain your situation better. Edit your question  and add more detail.